# ¿Es correcto usar método POST para recoger datos de una base de datos?

Tags: api, aws

¿Imagino que no será buena practica pero, me podría servir sin problemas?

Estoy montando una API REST en Api Gateway de AWS, con la intención de que el backend de mi app sea 100% serverless.

Resulta que tengo una función lambda que según los parámetros que le pases (ejemplo: "UserId":3) te devuelve los datos de la base de datos del UserId con id 3.

```javascript
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
// Pasa UserId en parámetros JSON
let scanningParameters = {
    Key: {
                UserId: event.UserId
    },
    TableName: 'Users'
}
```

La petición a la que debería estar unido esta función lambda debería ser una petición GET porque realmente estoy pidiendo a la base de datos unos datos en concreto para retornar hacia mi app front-end, sin embargo tuve que unir esta función a una petición POST en API Gateway, porque obviamente no puedo pasar parámetros JSON en una petición GET.

¿Puedo seguir construyendo la API REST con esta lógica, o debería cambiarlo? El caso es que la unica manera que se me ocurre de escribir esta función. Si lo quiero hacer con peticiones GET tendria que cambiar el codigo de la funcion lambda y desconozco como.

Comment: por que no puedes pasar parametros json en una peticion GET? un json es una cadena al fin y al cabo, no? quiero decir, cuando se transmite un json, realmente transmites una cadena. Otra cosa es que quieras mantenerlo como "objeto"

Comment: @Jakala Desconozco bastante como funciona el servicio de AWS en este sentido. No he logrado hacerlo funcionar así :(

Comment: como tal, si cambias ese uso, aunque pueda funcionarte, ya no lo puedes llamar "api rest". sera otra cosa, pero rest no :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De funcionar funcionará si haces todas tus peticiones por `POST`, tecnicamente puedes hacer todo con `POST` pero usar las otras peticiones organizará tus endpoints, recuerda que no sólo tienes `GET` o `POST`, sino también `DELETE` y `PUT` con los que completarás el esquema **CRUD**:

```
    Create -> POST
    Read -> GET
    Update -> PUT
    Delete -> DELETE
```

Ahora, la idea de un request para leer datos de una BD es esa, obtener datos, para lo cual no necesitas enviar mucha información más que un ID (o algunos ID) y filtros, esto es completamente soportado con una petición `GET`, donde el ID (o los IDs) formarían parte de la URL y los filtros como parámetros, p.e. para un usuario con ID 3:

```
    GET: /users/3
```

Ahora, para configurar eso en AWS en tu configuración de Api Gateway necesitas crear un recurso con `{UserId}` con el método `GET`, quedando tu ruta como:

```
    /users/{UserId}
```

Y por último, en tu función Lambda cambiar tu código para leer ese parámetro:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Pasa UserId en parámetros JSON
    let scanningParameters = {
        Key: {
            UserId: event.pathParameters.UserId // <-- Obteniendo los parámetros de la URL
        },
        TableName: 'Users'
    }
```

Recuerda que si estás enviando mucha información para solamente obtener registros probablemente necesites reestructurar tu código o incluso tu Base de Datos o que quizás no sólo estés obteniendo recursos sino haciendo algo más.

Answer (score 1):

Como vos decis, la idea es que peticiones las hagas por GET.
Los parámetros los tendrias que pasar por la URL por ejemplo:

```
/get-records?filterby=name&orderby=name
```

La diferencia entre GET y POST mas alla de la conocida es que los GET los puedes cachear por el browser (con las debidas configuraciones)

Pero, capaz que vos hablas de como pasarle el UserId... Aca tendrias que utilizar token `(JWT, Bearer)` para poder indentificar el usuario de cada peticion.

Comment: Una pregunta, he implementado el GET y me sale Missing Authentication Token cuando intento hacer una request. Sabes por qué puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

Curiosamente, sí puedes enviar un JSON en la *carga útil* de un mensaje GET.

El RFC7230 propone:

> La presencia de un cuerpo de mensaje en una petición esta señalizada por una cabecera *Content-Length* ó *Transfer-encoding*.
>
> El enmarcado de mensajes de petición es independiente de la semántica del método, incluso si el método no define algún uso del cuerpo del mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

Para las buenas practicas sí es recomendable usar una petición de método `GET` ya que estas indicarían que la petición que quieres hacer es para obtener una información pero he visto varias *APIs* que usan el `POST` nada más para simplificar la documentación en que todas las rutas son de método `POST`.

También cabe recordar que no es sugerible hacer que un método `GET` funcione como si fuera un `POST`, `PUT` y `DELETE`, yo he notado que el `GET` tiene una limitante de envío de información dentro del *body* de la petición .

Comment: "yo he notado que el GET tiene una limitante de envío de información dentro del body de la petición" -> No, el GET no tiene body, directamente. Si quieres enviar datos con un GET los envías a través de pathParams o queryParams, no en el body.

Comment: Tienes razón, disculpen desinformar sobre ello. Muchas gracias por tu correción.